# Python import error in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror

A few hours back, I had followed [this link](http://ermaker.github.io/blog/2015/09/08/get-started-with-keras-for-beginners.html) and had successfully installed `numpy`, `keras`, `theano` and all the dependencies. I even checked to see if `keras` was working using

`curl -sSL https://github.com/fchollet/keras/raw/master/examples/mnist_mlp.py | python`

as suggested on that blog and it worked perfectly. I then had to run a few downloads and closed the terminal. Now when I open the python shell in the terminal using the `python` command, and type in `import keras` or `import numpy`, it causes an `Import Error`. I had tested all of this on my terminal and not in a `virtualenv`. What on earth is the problem and how can I fix it?

EDIT:
I looked around a little more and realised that everytime I close the terminal, I have to follow the instructions in that link from `conda install -y theano` part. Why is this and how can I fix this?

Comment: Maybe it is not the right version of python interpreter?

Comment: I had tested it on the python shell and everything worked perfectly before. Why would it not work in the shell again?

Comment: You can try this: `python -m pip install keras` to figure out if it is there installed.